# In scons, how to specify path of the target?

Tags: linux, scons

I'm new to scons. I was trying to specify the path of the target. I don't want the executable to be generated in the same folder, in which the SConstruct file resides.

I tried the following:
(Suppose the SConstruct file resides in some folder 'Foo')

```
env.Program(
    #executable name
    target="~/Desktop/my_executable", 
     ...
```

However this **creates** directories `Foo/~/Desktop/` and places the target `my_executable` into the leaf directory.

How do I get scons to generate the target inside some fixed folder? I'm using linux.

Comment: By default, SCons will create the targets in the same dir. If you want otherwise, refer to this related question/answers, where the SCons VariantDir() and/or SConsctipr() functions are described: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15411176/1158895

Comment: @Brady - You should post that as an answer. Then we can vote it up! (Also typo on SConscript)

Comment: @bdbaddog, Thanks, but the answer Im referring to is also mine, and I didnt want to repeat. I guess you could vote up the referenced answer :)